# Administrador de controladores ODBC - La arquitectura del DSN especificado no coincide entre el controlador y la aplicación PHP ACCESS

Tags: php, xampp, ms-access, odbc, mdb

antes de empezar, debo comentar que ya he probado todo lo de ODBC 32 y 64 bits que he visto en otros post de este foro y de otros lugares.

Actualmente tengo un Windows Server 2022 (también he probado con Windows 10 y me pasa igual) con varias versiones de XAMPP pr y estoy intentando acceder a un .mdb con el siguiente código:

```
    $dsn = "prueba";
    $usuario = "";
    $clave="";
    // Se realiza la conexón con los datos especificados anteriormente
    $conn = odbc_connect($dsn,$usuario,$clave);
```

He intentado creando un conector en la dirección C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe y en C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe con el nombre prueba y apuntando a la base de datos de prueba. Ya he probado en varios equipos y siempre me pasa lo mismo, no se qué estoy haciendo mal.

Por favor, necesito ayuda urgente para un proyecto, paso imágenes para dar más datos. Gracias.

[image: DSN en 32 bits]

[image: Versión de php]

[image: Versión odbc]